# Grammar - Active or passive form

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

> She was faced with imminent death.

Is this sentence passive or active form?

Active form should be :

> She faced with imminent death.

Is this right?

Comment: Is this an exercise? Where did you get it? Short passive, i.e passive without an agent, cannot be converted into an active voice. Or did you mean **by emminent death**?

Comment: *Imminent death faced her*.  Just as with "The ball was kicked by him - > He kicked the ball",     *she* moves into object position and becomes *her*   and "with imminent death" becomes "imminent death" and is moved into subject position.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is indeed in the passive voice, as the subject is acted upon by the past participle form of a verb.

However, the active voice should be:

- She faced  imminent death.

In this case the transitive verb has a direct object, and thus needs no preposition in between.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> {She} {was bitten} {by a rat} ->   A rat bit her.
>
> {She} {was faced} {with death} ->  Death faced her.
>
> She was confronted by a grim prospect. -> A grim prospect confronted her.
>
> She was confronted with a difficult choice. -> A difficult choice confronted her.
>
> She was appalled by the high prices. -> The high prices appalled her.
>
> She was disappointed with the result. -> The result disappointed her.
>
> The reaction was accelerated with a catalyst. -> A catalyst accelerated the reaction.

Comment: "with" can replace "by" in passive voice?

Comment: Some people treat the past participles here as participial predicate adjectives denoting state, and would deny that these are instances of the passive.  But I see no reason to make that distinction since the preposition **with** can denote *instrumentality* just like **by**.